# How do I make sudo!! add a space after sudo?

Tags: raspbian, bash, sudo

When I type sudo!! it never puts a space between sudo and anything.
How do I make sudo!! add a space?

Example:

```
nano text.txt
sudo!!
sudonano text.txt
```

Maybe I am using it wrong but it never works unless I add a space after sudo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use

```
sudo !!
```

instead of `sudo!!`. This is intended behaviour. The `!!` [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Designators.html#Word-Designators), as stated in the documentation:

> designates the preceding command. When you type this, the preceding command is repeated [in toto](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_toto).

It is simply as if `!!` were replaced with a find/replace with the contents of the last line. Naturally, since your line didn't start with a space, a space isn't included in the expansion.

Comment: xD , Ahhhaha, I feel silly now. Thanks a bunch for clarifying.